# Amazon Firefly - Adding Plugin to App

Tags: android, android-service, amazon-firefly

With the release of the Firefly SDK yesterday I'm rushing to incorporate it into my app. I'm currently having a problem adding a service to my AndroidManifest file.

```
<service
        android:name="com.company.android.amazon.Plugin"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.amazon.mw.permission.PLUGIN_CONSUMER">
        <!-- Set the intent filter for Firefly plugin -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="amazon.intent.action.mw.IMPORT_PLUGIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

The error says:

```
`'com.company.android.amazon.Plugin' is not assignable to 'android.app.Service'
  Validates resource references inside Android XML files.`
```

Where company and Plugin are generic and I've actually labeled them more priecise for my companies sake.
I've extended Plugin from SimplePlugin with the Amazon Firefly SDK installed.

Also related question, does my 'min' and 'target' have to be api level 17? I understand the following needs to be true:

```
compileSdkVersion "Amazon.com:Amazon Fire Phone SDK Addon:17"

buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"
```

Lastly: I've gone ahead an submitted in the Firefly forum at Amazon here (http://forums.developer.amazon.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=3636&tstart=0) if anyone wants to see the responses.

Comment: Also to note, I've posted this within Amazon's Firefly Forums which although recently created are all but dead. I have faith in the SO community though

Comment: Can anyone confirm that the min and target Sdk Versions have to be set to 17? Thats what the Amazon rep mentioned, however my third party libraries I use require api level 19.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I'll go ahead and answer my own question here. I submitted the ticket to Amazon under the Firefly forum and they finally came back to me.

http://forums.developer.amazon.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=3636&tstart=0

The reason I was getting the error in my Manifest file  was because my targetSDKVersion was set to 19. Currently the Fire OS Supports up too api level 17. This means any third party libraries that use level 19 will also need to be transitioned to 17 or you'll have to wait for Amazon to upgrade Fire OS.

Unfortunately this isn't what I wanted to hear, but there is no way around it. Many of my libraries are heavily incorporated into my app and it would take more time trying to recompile them with the lower sdk.

Hope this can help anyone else trying to compile their Android app with the Firefly SDK!

Comment: Wow that is so cray arrogant of Amazon to implement it like this and then not keeping up with the latest relase - jeeeesus!

Comment: Agreed @slott if anything, its helped me cut down my current library stack and depend more on the core fundamentals giving a fuller android experience. It takes a lot of work, and potentially not even possible for some apps at this point though.

Comment: I have an app that have to support this and the only viable solution I see is to have a separate branch for the firefly as I can't get google maps etc. etc. working with the firefly target. It would have been easier if they had made a simple .jar file...